# Am I setting up domain correctly for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I want to prevent my NodeJS app from crashing and read that using domain is the way to do it. I'm still a little confused though but followed what I saw to get it set up. Is this set up correctly? Do I need to change anything? Thanks.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var d = require('domain').create();

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {

    //set up express
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(function(req,res){
        res.redirect('/error');
    });

});


//launch
d.on('error', function(er) {
    console.log('Error!', er.message);
});

d.run(function() {
    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
        console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
});
```

When I create in error in one of my route files it seems to work correctly, but the error isn't logging. Should I have it log to a file or something so I can check for errors later on?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you're doing is a bad practice according to the NodeJS documentation, since you can start a memory leak every time the error occurs. There's an example on the [domain api docs page](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) of the right way to do it.  I'm not sure why console.log isn't working, however -- a log file is probably a good idea.  Also be aware that the api for domain is still unstable and may change.

In short you should handle your errors gracefully and start a new worker process when an unexpected an error occurs (using the cluster module to start and stop workers that run into problems).

From the docs, this is what you're *not* supposed to do, which looks awfully close to what you're doing:

```
// XXX WARNING!  BAD IDEA!

var d = require('domain').create();
d.on('error', function(er) {
  // The error won't crash the process, but what it does is worse!
  // Though we've prevented abrupt process restarting, we are leaking
  // resources like crazy if this ever happens.
  // This is no better than process.on('uncaughtException')!
  console.log('error, but oh well', er.message);
});
d.run(function() {
  require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    handleRequest(req, res);
  }).listen(PORT);
});
```